# Log in timer running even program is closed

Tags: vb.net, timer

I made a system in vb 2010.My log in has a timer that disable the user 10 seconds from typing log in info after failing to type the correct log in info for 3 times. What I want to do is after I close the program, and reopen it again, i want the timer to resume its countdown where it stopped when it was closed. Is is possbile?

```
 If Button1.Enabled = False Then
        Timer1.Start()
        Label3.Show()
        Timer1.Interval = 1000


        Second = Second - 1

        Label3.Text = "You must wait " & Second & " second/s before logging in again"



        If Second = 0 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Second = 10
            Button1.Enabled = True
            TextBox1.Enabled = True
            TextBox2.Enabled = True
            Button2.Enabled = True

            Label3.Hide()
            TextBox1.Text = ("")
            TextBox2.Text = ("")




        End If
    End If
```

Comment: You reading in the login information from a database?

Comment: There are several ways: Database, File, Registry, ...

Comment: Yes, my log in infos are in a database.